# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: pack.Series

Tags: java, jboss

everyone, I try to create a web application that cares about COVID19, so I have 2 entites.
**MultiSeries:**

```
package pack;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class MultiSeries {
    
    /** Attributes of contact */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Series> series;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Collection<Series> getSeries() {
        return this.series;
    }
    
    public void setSeries(Collection<Series> series) {
        this.series = series;
    }
    
}
```

**Series:**

```
package pack;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Series {
    
    /** Attributes of contact */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int value;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, I have rest web service **Facade**:

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class Facade {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    
    /**
     * Generate unique ID from UUID
     * @return long value representing UUID
     */
    public Long generateUniqueId() {
        long val = -1;
        do {
            final UUID uid = UUID.randomUUID();
            final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
            buffer.putLong(uid.getLeastSignificantBits());
            buffer.putLong(uid.getMostSignificantBits());
            final BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(buffer.array());
            val = bi.longValue();
        }
        while (val < 0);
            return val;
    }
    
    /**
     * Update the database with the current data of new cases
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/new_cases")
    public void updateNewCases() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            MultiSeries multiSeries = new MultiSeries();
            multiSeries.setId(generateUniqueId());
            multiSeries.setName("New_cases");
            ArrayList<Series> series = new ArrayList<>();
            List<List<String>> records = CSVUtility.parseCSVFile();
            for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
                Series item = new Series();
                item.setId(generateUniqueId());
                item.setName(records.get(i).get(0));
                item.setValue(Float.valueOf(records.get(i).get(2)).intValue());
                series.add(item);
            }
            multiSeries.setSeries(series);
            em.persist(multiSeries);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when execute `curl --request POST http://localhost:8080/AntiCOVID/rest/new_cases`, I get
this :

```
03:54:51,764 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: pack.MultiSeries
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.hibernate@5.3.14.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.hibernate@5.3.14.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.hibernate@5.3.14.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.hibernate@5.3.14.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.hibernate@5.3.14.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
03:54:51,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.jpa@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.AntiCOVID.war//pack.Facade.updateNewCases(Facade.java:68)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
03:54:51,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.ee@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)...
```

You will find github.com/MOUDDENEHamza/ENSEEIHT/blob/master/trace
the complete trace.
And I dont understand where is the problem with this. And when I use merge rather then persist he said that he don't find Series with a given id.

Comment: Could you paste the complete stack trace?

Comment: You will find it here https://github.com/MOUDDENEHamza/ENSEEIHT/blob/master/trace

Comment: I'm not very versed with jboss but in the PoJo the id is annotated with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`  (which probably means the id is generated on its own) but then you set the id in . Have you tried changing `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`  to something else, like say`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` but i still have the same problem